# Passing variables to Power BI query

Tags: powerbi

I have multiple queries in Power BI and all of them use an iKey Value. I want to change this value to a variable for all queries and set it at a single location which would automatically reflect in multiple power BI queries.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: yes, create a blank query `variable = value` and use it in other queries: `measure = variable + 1`

Comment: When you say "query", are you talking about a DAX expression for a new column, table, or measure? Or are you talking about queries that are pulling your data into Power BI? Can you give a couple examples?